# Google ChartWrapper not working on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to insert some google charts on a wordpress website and the only graphs that are not being ehxibited are those built using ChartWrapper. (Outside of wordpress it works just fine)

All graphs using DrawChart or GeoChart are working fine.

The error thrown is: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Y' of null**

Does someone have a hint on how to solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'geochart','controls'], 'language': 'pt-BR'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawGID);

    function drawGID() {
        var consulta14 = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'UF', 'Saldo' FROM 1tW9OA8z2KOFNwwXkK4A2lV3SK7221QAfjdG2fGUZ");
        var query14 = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?rows:id=1&tq=' + consulta14);
        query14.send(saldo_empregos_UF);
    }

function saldo_empregos_UF(response) {

        var tabela = response.getDataTable();
        var dados = new google.visualization.DataView(tabela);
        dados.setColumns([0,
        1,
        {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        }
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'BarChart',
            containerId: 'chart_saldo_empregos_UF',
            dataTable: dados,
            options: {
                title: "Saldo de empregos gerados por MPE em Set/2017, por estado",
                height: 1100,
                legend: 'none'
            }
        });
        chart.draw();
    }

// ]]>
</script>

<div id="chart_saldo_empregos_UF"></div>
```

Comment: I think you need to change `dataTable: dados,` to `view: dados,`. Or remove it and change `chart.draw()` to `chart.draw(dados)`. Not tested though.

Comment: I've tried both and it didn't work =/
My code works fine outside wordpress but inside does not.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682278/google-charts-in-wordpress